# How to register a font for free uses

Tags: fonts, licensing

I had developed a font few days ago. And i wanted to make it available for all for personal or commercial uses without modifying the font file.

Where can i register it? please suggest some references.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly about programming / coding / software development. See the [[help/on-topic]] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked [The League of Moveable Type](http://blog.theleagueofmoveabletype.com/) ? They have a collaborative blog into which you could post. This would allow to leave a trackable mark that you're the author and allow you to add the chosen licence.

You could also [create](https://github.com/repositories/new) a GitHub repository, commit your font, some screenshots and add an additional licence.txt file.

You could then apply to [Google Font Directory](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/submitafont/), for instance, and provide a link to your GitHub repository.

Comment: I suppose, this is for informing about my work in a community. There is nothing like registration.

Comment: @articlestack:  Well, posting your font in their blog allow to leave a trackable mark that you're the author and allow you to add the chosen licence.

Comment: @articlestack: You could also create a gitHub repository, commit your font and add an additional licence.txt file.

Comment: 1+ for gitHub suggestion. But i dint found any exiting project on github which is a font only.

Comment: Updated the answer to make it more complete.

Comment: I had accepted you ans. although i uploaded my font on sourceforge.net. Link for the same is http://sourceforge.net/projects/amtycurrency/

Answer (score 0):

Just include a Creative Commons license with the distribution .zip (or whatever package you use to distribute the font)

Check out: http://creativecommons.org/

Comment: Creative Commons license confuse me always. As per my understanding, you can show any CC license(as per need). But we can not claim that the software/font/image/etc really belongs to us or we register it first. (in case someone makes its copy and he also shows the CC license)

Comment: In that case, register it for a copyright first-- that's the ironclad way to prove you invented/developed anything. THEN release it under CC.

Comment: :-) this is the problem only where & how to take copyright? well no issue, As per Em suggestion I had uploaded it on sourceforge.net. I'll sum up this question soon.

Comment: http://copyright.gov/ the Google is your friend ;)

Comment: In my opinion, No body would like to pay fees for licensing open source application. specially if he is not an organization